# why quotes " in Verbatime become tilde when adding \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} with tex4ht?

Tags: tex4ht, font-encodings, times

There seems to be another strange interaction with packages here with tex4ht. I do not know if this is a feature of these packages that one is not supposed to mix them, or a bug. But it only shows up in the HTML not in the pdf.

This MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancybox,fancyvrb}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
htlatex foo.tex "htm,3"
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Now `htlatex foo.tex` gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The HTML is

```
</head><body >
   <div class="fancyvrb" id="fancyvrb1"><a 
 id="x1-3r1"></a><span 
class="pcrr8t-x-x-120">&#x00A0;</span><span 
class="pcrr8t-x-x-120">&#x00A0;htlatex</span><span 
class="pcrr8t-x-x-120">&#x00A0;foo.tex</span><span 
class="pcrr8t-x-x-120">&#x00A0;~htm,3~</span></div>    
</body></html>
```

When I comment either the package `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or `\usepackage{times}`, then problem goes away and I get:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

with HTML source

```
</head><body >
   <div class="fancyvrb" id="fancyvrb1"><a 
 id="x1-3r1"></a><span 
class="pcrr7t-x-x-120">&#x00A0;</span><span 
class="pcrr7t-x-x-120">&#x00A0;htlatex</span><span 
class="pcrr7t-x-x-120">&#x00A0;foo.tex</span><span 
class="pcrr7t-x-x-120">&#x00A0;"htm,3"</span></div>    
</body></html>
```

I do not know what `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` does, but I remember reading it is good to have always? I use the `times` package to make the fonts more dark and more compact, which I like, even though I was told it is very old package. I [had problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220555/why-using-newtxtext-newtxmath-packages-breaks-mathml-generation-in-tex4ht) using `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` with tex4ht (which I understand they replace the `times` package?), so I went back to using `times`. But I now I noticed this new problem on some of the pages I have.

I thought someone might be able to explain why this problem shows up.

texlive 2014.

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
fancybox.sty    2010/05/15 1.4
fancyvrb.sty    2008/02/07
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
   times.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR) 
   t1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/ptm.
   t1pcr.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/pcr.
 ***********
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the `bchr8t.htf`. It has `'&#x007E;'` at the place where `lm-ec.htf` has `'&#x0022;'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems two errors were presented here, both of them in `tex4ht` hyper fonts. When we modify your sample slightly:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancybox,fancyvrb}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
htlatex foo.tex "htm,3"
\end{Verbatim}


\begin{verbatim}
htlatex foo.tex "htm,3"
\end{verbatim}
\font\x=pcrr8t
\x
htlatex foo.tex "htm,3"
\end{document}
```

we can see that this error does have nothing to do with `fancyvrb` package:

[image]

not only there are tildes instead of double quotes, text is also bold. text in plain is not in verbatim, because styling information in hyper fonts is not being used.

font used for code blocks in your example is `pcrr8t` and corresponding hyper font is `pcrr8t.htf`:

```
.bchr8t
htfcss: pcrr8t font-weight: bold;
```

two types of hyper fonts exists in `tex4ht` one provides values used for characters, other points to hyper font of the first type and add css style. `pcrr8t.htf` is this second type, pointing to `bchr8t.htf`. the error here is `font-weight`, which shouldn't be bold, but `monospaced` instead.

the other problem, as Ulrike pointed out, is wrong code for double quotes in `bchr8t.htf`. correct content of these files is following:

`pcrr8t.htf`:

```
.bchr8t
htfcss: pcrr8t font-weight: monospaced;
```

and `bchr8t.htf`:

```
bchr8t 0 255
'&#x0300;' ''  grave           0 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
'&#x0301;' ''  acute           1 % bchr8t.htf                 2009-05-06 %
'&#x0302;' ''  circumflex      2 % Copyright (C) 2004--2009 Eitan M. Gurari %
'&#x0303;' ''  breve           3 %                                                                    %
'&#x0308;' ''  diaeresis       4 % This work may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions  %
'&#x030B;' ''  double acute    5 % of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3 of this    %
'&#x030A;' ''  ring above      6 % license or (at your option) any later version. The latest version  %
'&#x030C;' ''  tilde           7 % of this license is in http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt and    %
'&#x0306;' ''  dieresis        8 % version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX version %
'&#x0304;' ''  overbar         9 % 2003/12/01 or later.                                               %
'&#x0307;' ''                 10 %  This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained". This      %
'&#x0327;' ''                 11 % Current Maintainer of this work is Eitan M. Gurari.                %
'&#x0328;' ''                 12 %                                                                    %
'&#x0326;' ''                 13 % If you modify this file your your adding a note of                 %
'&#x2039;' '' < guillement    14 % your own after this copyright note will be appreciated.            %
'&#x203A;' ''                 15 %                                                                    %
'&#x201C;' ''                 16 %                                          gurari@cse.ohio-state.edu %
'&#x201D;' ''                 17 %                              http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari %
'&#x201E;' ''                 18 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
'&#x00AB;' ''                 19 
'&#x00BB;' ''                 20
'&#x2013;' ''                 21
'&#x2014;' ''                 22
'' ''                         23
'&#x25FE;' ''                 24
'&#x0131;' '' dotlessi        25
'&#x25AE;' ''                 26
'&#xFB00;' ''  &fflig;        27
'&#xFB01;' ''  &filig;        28
'&#xFB02;' ''  &fllig;        29
'&#xFB03;' ''  &ffilig;       30
'&#xFB04;' ''  &ffllig;       31
'&#x2423;' ''  visible space  32
'!' ''                        33
'&#x0022;' '' double quotes     34
'#' ''                        35
'$' ''                        36
'%' ''                        37
'&#x0026;' ''  ampersand      38
'&#x2019;' ''                 39
'&#x0028;' ''                 40
'&#x0029;' ''                 41
'*' ''                 42
'+' ''                 43
',' ''                 44
'-' ''                 45
'.' ''                 46
'/' ''                 47
'0' ''                 48
'1' ''                 49
'2' ''                 50
'3' ''                 51
'4' ''                 52
'5' ''                 53
'6' ''                 54
'7' ''                 55
'8' ''                 56
'9' ''                 57
':' ''                 58
';' ''                 59
'&#x003C;' ''          60
'=' ''                 61
'&#x003E;' ''          62
'?' ''                 63
'@' ''                 64
'A' ''                 65
'B' ''                 66
'C' ''                 67
'D' ''                 68
'E' ''                 69
'F' ''                 70
'G' ''                 71
'H' ''                 72
'I' ''                 73
'J' ''                 74
'K' ''                 75
'L' ''                 76
'M' ''                 77
'N' ''                 78
'O' ''                 79
'P' ''                 80
'Q' ''                 81
'R' ''                 82
'S' ''                 83
'T' ''                 84
'U' ''                 85
'V' ''                 86
'W' ''                 87
'X' ''                 88
'Y' ''                 89
'Z' ''                 90
'&#x005B;' ''                 91
'&#x005C;' ''          92
'&#x005D;' ''                 93
'&#x005E;' ''          94
'_' ''                 95
'&#x2018;' ''          96
'a' ''                 97
'b' ''                 98
'c' ''                 99
'd' ''                100
'e' ''                101
'f' ''                102
'g' ''                103
'h' ''                104
'i' ''                105
'j' ''                106
'k' ''                107
'l' ''                108
'm' ''                109
'n' ''                110
'o' ''                111
'p' ''                112
'q' ''                113
'r' ''                114
's' ''                115
't' ''                116
'u' ''                117
'v' ''                118
'w' ''                119
'x' ''                120
'y' ''                121
'z' ''                122
'&#x007B;' ''                123
'|' ''                124
'&#x007D;' ''                125
'~' ''                126
'&#x0331;' ''         127
'&#x0102;' '' Abreve  128
'&#x0104;' '' Aogonek 129
'&#x0106;' '' Cacute  130
'&#x010C;' '' Ccaron  131
'&#x010E;' '' Dcaron  132
'&#x011A;' '' Ecaron  133
'&#x0118;' '' Eogonek 134
'&#x011E;' '' Gbreve  135
'&#x0139;' '' Lacute  136
'&#x013D;' '' Lcaron  137
'&#x0141;' '' Lslash  138
'&#x00AB;' '' Nacute  139
'&#x0147;' '' Ncaron  140
'&#x25FE;' ''         141
'&#x0150;' '' Ohungarumlaut  142
'&#x0154;' '' Racute  143
'&#x0158;' '' Rcaron  144
'&#x015A;' '' Sacute  145
'&#x0160;' '' Scaron  146
'&#x0218;' '' Scommaaccent  147
'&#x0164;' '' Tcaron        148
'&#x021A;' '' Tcommaaccent  149
'&#x0170;' '' Uhungarumlaut 150
'&#x016E;' '' Uring         151
'&#x0178;' '' Ydieresis     152
'&#x0179;' '' Zacute        153
'&#x017E;' '' Zcaron        154
'&#x017B;' '' Zdotaccent    155
'&#x0132;' '' IJ            156
'&#x0130;' '' Idotaccent    157
'&#x0111;' '' dcroat        158
'&#x2A40;' '' section       159
'&#x0103;' '' abreve   160
'&#x0105;' '' aogonek  161
'&#x0107;' '' cacute   162
'&#x010D;' '' ccaron   163
'&#x010F;' '' dcaron   164
'&#x011B;' '' ecaron   165
'&#x0118;' '' eogonek  166
'&#x012E;' '' gbreve   167
'&#x013A;' '' lacute   168
'&#x013E;' '' lcaron   169
'&#x0142;' '' lslash   170
'&#x0144;' '' nacute   171
'&#x0148;' '' ncaron   172
'&#x25FE;' ''          173
'&#x0151;' '' ohungarumlaut   174
'&#x0155;' '' racute          175
'&#x0159;' '' rcaron          176
'&#x015B;' '' sacute          177
'&#x0160;' '' scaron          178
'&#x0219;' '' scommaaccent    179
'&#x0165;' '' tcaron          180
'&#x021B;' '' tcommaaccent    181
'&#x0171;' '' uhungarumlaut   182
'&#x016F;' '' uring           183
'&#x00FF;' '' ydieresis       184
'&#x017A;' '' zacute          185
'&#x017E;' '' zcaron          186
'&#x017C;' '' zdotaccent      187
'&#x0133;' '' ij              188
'&#x00A1;' '' exclamdown      189
'&#x00BF;' '' questiondown    190
'&#x00A3;' '' sterling        191
'&#x00C0;' '' Agrave       192
'&#x00C1;' '' Aacute       193
'&#x00C2;' '' Acircumflex  194
'&#x00C3;' '' Atilde       195
'&#x00C4;' '' Adieresis    196
'&#x00E5;' '' Aring        197
'&#x00C6;' '' AE           198
'&#x00C7;' '' Ccedilla     199
'&#x00C8;' '' Egrave       200
'&#x00E9;' '' Eacute       201
'&#x00CA;' '' Ecircumflex  202
'&#x00CB;' '' Edieresis    203
'&#x00CC;' '' Igrave       204
'&#x00CD;' '' Iacute       205
'&#x00CE;' '' Icircumflex  206
'&#x00AF;' '' Idieresis    207
'&#x00D0;' '' Eth          208
'&#x0143;' '' Ntilde       209
'&#x00D2;' '' Ograve       210
'&#x00D3;' '' Oacute       211
'&#x00D4;' '' Ocircumflex  212
'&#x00D5;' '' Otilde       213
'&#x00D6;' '' Odieresis    214
'&#x00D7;' '' multiply     215
'&#x00D8;' '' Oslash       216
'&#x00D9;' '' Ugrave       217
'&#x00DA;' '' Uacute       218
'&#x00DB;' '' Ucircumflex  219
'&#x00DC;' '' Udieresis    220
'&#x00DD;' '' Yacute       221
'&#x00DE;' '' Thorn        222
'&#x00DF;' '' germandbls   223
'&#x00E0;' '' agrave       224
'&#x00E1;' '' aacute       225
'&#x00E2;' '' acircumflex  226
'&#x00E3;' '' atilde       227
'&#x00E4;' '' adieresis    228
'&#x00E5;' '' aring        229
'&#x00E6;' '' ae           230
'&#x00E7;' '' ccedilla     231
'&#x00E8;' '' egrave       232
'&#x00E9;' '' eacute       233
'&#x00CA;' '' ecircumflex  234
'&#x00EB;' '' edieresis    235
'&#x00EC;' '' igrave       236
'&#x00ED;' '' iacute       237
'&#x00EE;' '' icircumflex  238
'&#x00EF;' '' idieresis    239
'&#x00F0;' '' eth          240
'&#x00F1;' '' ntilde       241
'&#x00F2;' '' ograve       242
'&#x00F3;' '' oacute       243
'&#x00F4;' '' ocircumflex  244
'&#x00F5;' '' otilde       255
'&#x00F6;' '' odieresis    246
'&#x00F7;' '' divide       247
'&#x00F8;' '' oslash       248
'&#x00F9;' '' ugrave       249
'&#x00FA;' '' uacute       250
'&#x00FB;' '' ucircumflex  251
'&#x00FC;' '' udieresis    252
'&#x00FD;' '' yacute       253
'&#x00FE;' '' thorn        254
'&#x00DF;' '' beta         255
bchr8t 0 255
```

save these files in folder with your document. the result is now:

[image]

these issues should be reported to `tex4ht` bug list, it seems that there is a lot of problems with hyper fonts

Comment: thanks. I just entered this in the tex4ht bug database, and few other issues I posted here before on tex4ht, so they get tracked.